# How to show a loading indicator in React Redux app while fetching the data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm new to React/Redux. I use a fetch api middleware in Redux app to process the APIs. It's ([redux-api-middleware](https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware)). I think it's the good way to process async api actions. But I find some cases which can't be resolve by myself.

As the homepage ([Lifecycle](https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware#lifecycle)) say, a fetch API lifecycle begins with dispatching a CALL_API action ends with dispatching a FSA action.

So my first case is showing/hiding a preloader when fetching APIs. The middleware will dispatch a FSA action at the beginning and dispatch a FSA action at the end. Both the actions are received by reducers which should be only doing some normal data processing. No UI operations, no more operations. Maybe I should save the processing status in state then render them when store updating.

But how to do this? A react component flow over the whole page? what happen with store updating from other actions? I mean they are more like events than state!

Even a worse case, what should I do when I have to use the native confirm dialog or alert dialog in redux/react apps? Where should they be put, actions or reducers?

Best wishes! Wish for replying.

Comment: Rolled back the last edit to this question as it changed the entire point of the question and answers below.

Comment: A event is the change of state!

Comment: Take a look at questrar. https://github.com/orar/questrar

Answer (score 157):

> I mean they are more like events than state!

I would not say so. I think loading indicators are a great case of UI that is easily described as a function of state: in this case, of a boolean variable. While [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35457449/458193) is correct, I would like to provide some code to go along with it.

In the [`async` example in Redux repo](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/async), reducer [updates a field called `isFetching`](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/fa96297e8980349678878027a37fa2612df438b5/examples/async/reducers/index.js#L26-L37):

```
case REQUEST_POSTS:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    isFetching: true,
    didInvalidate: false
  })
case RECEIVE_POSTS:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    isFetching: false,
    didInvalidate: false,
    items: action.posts,
    lastUpdated: action.receivedAt
```

The component uses `connect()` from React Redux to subscribe to the store’s state and [returns `isFetching` as part of the `mapStateToProps()` return value](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/fa96297e8980349678878027a37fa2612df438b5/examples/async/containers/App.js#L93) so it is available in the connected component’s props:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { selectedReddit, postsByReddit } = state
  const {
    isFetching,
    lastUpdated,
    items: posts
  } = postsByReddit[selectedReddit] || {
    isFetching: true,
    items: []
  }

  return {
    selectedReddit,
    posts,
    isFetching,
    lastUpdated
  }
}
```

Finally, the component [uses `isFetching` prop in the `render()` function](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/fa96297e8980349678878027a37fa2612df438b5/examples/async/containers/App.js#L61) to render a “Loading...” label (which could conceivably be a spinner instead):

```
{isEmpty
  ? (isFetching ? <h2>Loading...</h2> : <h2>Empty.</h2>)
  : <div style={{ opacity: isFetching ? 0.5 : 1 }}>
      <Posts posts={posts} />
    </div>
}
```

> Even a worse case, what should I do when I have to use the native confirm dialog or alert dialog in redux/react apps? Where should they be put, actions or reducers?

Any side effects (and showing a dialog is most certainly a side effect) do not belong in reducers. Think of reducers as passive “builders of state”. They don’t really “do” things.

If you wish to show an alert, either do this from a component before dispatching an action, or do this from an action creator. By the time an action is dispatched, it is too late to perform side effects in response to it.

For every rule, there is an exception. Sometimes your side effect logic is so complicated you actually *want* to couple them either to specific action types or to specific reducers. In this case check out advanced projects like [Redux Saga](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga) and [Redux Loop](https://github.com/raisemarketplace/redux-loop). Only do this when you are comfortable with vanilla Redux and have a real problem of scattered side effects you’d like to make more manageable.

Comment: What if I have multiple fetches going? Then one variable would not be enough though.

Comment: @philk if you have multiple fetches you can group them with `Promise.all` into a single promise and then dispatch a single action for all the fetches. Or you have to maintain multiple `isFetching` variables in your state.

Comment: Please take a careful look at the example I link to. There more than one `isFetching` flag. It is set for every set of objects that is being fetched. You can use reducer composition to implement that.

Comment: @DanAbramov what if we have just an object of entities (or just an array) and we don't cache data but want to load new items on every visit of the page? On the second visit of the page, initially we show old data then spinner and only after that a new data...

Comment: Note that if the request fails, and `RECEIVE_POSTS` is never triggered, the loading sign will remain in place unless you've created some sort of timeout to show an `error loading` message.

Comment: I've checked the `async` example and the `isFetching` is only for `posts` reducer. But what if we have some other `isFetching`s, how to manage that? Maybe there's an example. Thank!

Comment: What to do when fetching is aborted by a page reload? In our case, we use redux-storage that loads the previous state from local storage. This means the loader is visible after the page reload. The request, however, was aborted so the success/fail actions will not be triggered. This means the loader will remain active infinitely.

Comment: @TomiS - I explicitly blacklist all of my isFetching properties from whatever redux persistence I'm using.

Comment: @DanAbramov, sometimes  split by set of objects is not enough
for example in case of search or/and filters,  its just different ways to load same entities, same for tree-based hierarchies when i can drill down  by parent

Comment: @TomiS - Or you can have a 'cancel all network events' action that you dispatch straight after createStore, (which will also fire if you pick up your store from localstorage) which resets all isFetching flags

Comment: What is the best way to do it? Set a button ID and dispatch it?

Answer (score 22):

Great answer Dan Abramov!
Just want to add that I was doing more or less exactly that in one of my apps (keeping isFetching as a boolean) and ended up having to make it an integer (which ends up reading as the number of outstanding requests) to support multiple simultaneous requests.

with boolean:

request 1 starts -> spinner on -> request 2 starts -> request 1 ends -> spinner off -> request 2 ends

with integer:

request 1 starts -> spinner on -> request 2 starts -> request 1 ends -> request 2 ends -> spinner off

```
case REQUEST_POSTS:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    isFetching: state.isFetching + 1,
    didInvalidate: false
  })
case RECEIVE_POSTS:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    isFetching: state.isFetching - 1,
    didInvalidate: false,
    items: action.posts,
    lastUpdated: action.receivedAt
```

Comment: This is reasonable. However most often you also want to store some *data* you fetch in addition to the flag. At this point you will need to have more than one object with `isFetching` flag. If you look closely at the example I linked to you will see that there is not one object with `isFetched` but many: one per subreddit (which is what is being fetched in that example).

Comment: oh. yeah i didn't notice that. however in my case i have one global isFetching entry in the state and a cache entry where the fetched data is stored, and for my purposes i only really care that some network activity is happening, it doesn't really matter what for

Comment: Yep! It depends on whether you want to show the fetching indicator in one or many places in the UI. In fact you can combine the two approaches and have *both* a global `fetchCounter` for some progress bar at the top of the screen and several specific `isFetching` flags for lists and pages.

Comment: If I have POST Requests in more than one file, how would I set state of isFetching to keep track of its current state?

Answer (score 13):

I'd like to add something. The real world example uses a field `isFetching` in the store to represent when a *collection* of items is being fetched. Any collection is generalized to a `pagination` reducer that can be connected to your components to track the state and show if a collection is loading.

It happened to me that I wanted to fetch details for an specific entity that doesn't fit in the pagination pattern. I wanted to have a state representing if the details are being fetched from the server but also I didn't want to have a reducer just for that.

To solve this I added another generic reducer called `fetching`. It works in a similar fashion to the pagination reducer and it's responsibility is just to *watch* a set of actions and generate new state with pairs `[entity, isFetching]`. That allows to `connect` the reducer to any component and to know if the app is currently fetching data not just for a collection but for an specific entity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Handling the loading of individual items and their status is rarely discussed!

Comment: When I have one component that depends on the action of another a quick and dirty way out is in your mapStateToProps combine them like this: isFetching: posts.isFetching || comments.isFetching - now you can block user interaction for both components when either one is being updated.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't happen upon this question until now, but since no answer is accepted I'll throw in my hat. I wrote a tool for this very job: [react-loader-factory](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loader-factory). It's got slightly more going on than Abramov's solution, but is more modular and convenient, since I didn't want to have to think after I wrote it.

There are four big pieces:

- Factory pattern: This allows you to quickly call the same function to set up which states mean "Loading" for your component, and which actions to dispatch. (This assumes that the component is responsible for starting the actions it waits on.) `const loaderWrapper = loaderFactory(actionsList, monitoredStates);`
- Wrapper: The component the Factory produces is a "higher order component" (like what `connect()` returns in Redux), so that you can just bolt it onto your existing stuff. `const LoadingChild = loaderWrapper(ChildComponent);`
- Action/Reducer interaction: The wrapper checks to see if a reducer it's plugged into contains keywords that tell it not to pass through to the component that needs data. The actions dispatched by the wrapper are expected to produce the associated keywords (the way redux-api-middleware dispatches `ACTION_SUCCESS` and `ACTION_REQUEST`, for example). (You could dispatch actions elsewhere and just monitor from the wrapper if you wanted, of course.)
- Throbber: The component you want to appear while the data your component depends on isn't ready. I added a little div in there so you can test it out without having to rig it up.

The module itself is independent of redux-api-middleware, but that's what I use it with, so here's some sample code from the README:

A component with a Loader wrapping it:

```
import React from 'react';
import { myAsyncAction } from '../actions';
import loaderFactory from 'react-loader-factory';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';

const actionsList = [myAsyncAction()];
const monitoredStates = ['ASYNC_REQUEST'];
const loaderWrapper = loaderFactory(actionsList, monitoredStates);

const LoadingChild = loaderWrapper(ChildComponent);

const containingComponent = props => {
  // Do whatever you need to do with your usual containing component 

  const childProps = { someProps: 'props' };

  return <LoadingChild { ...childProps } />;
}
```

A reducer for the Loader to monitor (although you can [wire it differently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loader-factory#optional-state-injector) if you want):

```
export function activeRequests(state = [], action) {
  const newState = state.slice();

  // regex that tests for an API action string ending with _REQUEST 
  const reqReg = new RegExp(/^[A-Z]+\_REQUEST$/g);
  // regex that tests for a API action string ending with _SUCCESS 
  const sucReg = new RegExp(/^[A-Z]+\_SUCCESS$/g);

  // if a _REQUEST comes in, add it to the activeRequests list 
  if (reqReg.test(action.type)) {
    newState.push(action.type);
  }

  // if a _SUCCESS comes in, delete its corresponding _REQUEST 
  if (sucReg.test(action.type)) {
    const reqType = action.type.split('_')[0].concat('_REQUEST');
    const deleteInd = state.indexOf(reqType);

    if (deleteInd !== -1) {
      newState.splice(deleteInd, 1);
    }
  }

  return newState;
}
```

I expect in the near future I'll add things like timeout and error to the module, but the pattern's not going to be very different.

---

The short answer to your question is:

1. Tie rendering to rendering code--use a wrapper around the component you need to render with the data like the one I showed above.
2. Add a reducer that makes the status of requests around the app you might care about easily digestible, so you don't have to think too hard about what is happening.
3. Events and state aren't really different.
4. The rest of your intuitions seem correct to me.

Answer (score 5):

Am I the only one thinking that loading indicators don't belong in a Redux store? I mean, I don't think it's part of an application's state per se..

Now, I work with Angular2, and what I do is that I have a "Loading" service which exposes different loading indicators via RxJS BehaviourSubjects.. I guess the mechanism is the same, I just don't store the information in Redux.

Users of the LoadingService just subscribe to those events they want to listen to..

My Redux action creators call the LoadingService whenever things need to change. UX components subscribe to the exposed observables...

Comment: this is why I like the idea of store, where all actions can be polled (ngrx and redux-logic), service is not functional, redux-logic - functional. [Nice reading](https://medium.com/@jeffbski/where-do-i-put-my-business-logic-in-a-react-redux-application-9253ef91ce1)

Comment: Hi, checking back more than a year after, just to say that I was very wrong. Of course UX state belongs in the application state. How stupid could I be?

Answer (score 3):

You can add change listeners to your stores, using either `connect()` from React Redux or the low-level `store.subscribe()` method. You should have the loading indicator in your store, which the store change handler can then check and update the component state. The component then renders the preloader if needed, based on the state.

`alert` and `confirm` shouldn't be a problem. They are blocking and alert doesn't even take any input from the user. With `confirm`, you can set state based on what the user has clicked if the user choice should affect component rendering. If not, you can store the choice as component member variable for later use.

Comment: about the alert/confirm code, where should they be put, actions or reducers?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with them, but honestly I'd put them in component code in most cases since they are part of UI, not the data layer.

Comment: some UI components act by triggering an event (event of changing status) instead of status itself. Such as an animation, showing/hiding preloader. How do you process them?

Comment: If you want to use a non-react component in your react app the generally used solution is to make a wrapper react component then use its lifecycle methods to initialize, update and destroy an instance of the non-react component. Most such components use placeholder elements in the DOM to initialize, and you'd render those in the react component's render method. You can read more about lifecycle methods here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

Comment: I have a case: a notification area at right-top corner, which contains one notification messages, each message shows up then disappears after 5 second. This component is out of the webview, provided by the host native app. It provides some js interface such as `addNofication(message)`. Another case is the preloaders which is also provided by host native app and triggered by its javascript API. I add a wrapper for those api, in `componentDidUpdate` of a React component. How do I design the props or state of this component?

Answer (score 3):

We have three types of notifications in our app, all of which are designed as aspects:

1. Loading indicator (modal or non-modal based on prop)
2. Error Popup (modal)
3. Notification snackbar (non-modal, self closing)

All three of these are at the top level of our app (Main), and wired through Redux as shown in the below code snippet. These props control display of their corresponding aspects.

I designed a proxy that handles all our API calls, thus all isFetching and (api) errors are mediated with actionCreators I import in the proxy. (As an aside, I also use webpack to inject a mock of the backing service for dev so we can work without server dependencies.)

Any other place in the app that needs to provide any type of notification simply imports the appropriate action. Snackbar & Error have params for messages to be displayed.

```
@connect(
// map state to props
state => ({
    isFetching      :state.main.get('isFetching'),   // ProgressIndicator
    notification    :state.main.get('notification'), // Snackbar
    error           :state.main.get('error')         // ErrorPopup
}),
// mapDispatchToProps
(dispatch) => { return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
}}
```

)
export default class Main extends React.Component{

Comment: I'm working on a similar setup with showing a loader/notifications.  I'm running into problems; would you have a gist or example of how you accomplish these tasks?

Answer (score 2):

I'm saving the urls such as::

```
isFetching: {
    /api/posts/1: true,
    api/posts/3: false,
    api/search?q=322: true,
}
```

And then I have a memorised selector (via reselect).

```
const getIsFetching = createSelector(
    state => state.isFetching,
    items => items => Object.keys(items).filter(item => items[item] === true).length > 0 ? true : false
);
```

To make the url unique in case of POST, I pass some variable as query.

And where I want to show an indicator, I simply use the getFetchCount variable

Comment: You can replace `Object.keys(items).filter(item => items[item] === true).length > 0 ? true : false` by `Object.keys(items).every(item => items[item])` by the way.

Comment: I think you meant `some` instead of `every`, but yes, too many not needed comparisons in the first proposed solution.

`Object.entries(items).some(([url, fetching]) => fetching);`