# Getting a JSON asynchronously and THEN rendering the component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, promise

I have a component, which has to download a JSON file and **then** iterate over it and display each element from the JSON on the screen.

I'm kinda new with React, used to be ng dev. In Angular, I used to do it with lifecycle hooks, e.g. ngOnInit/ngAfterViewInit (get some JSON file and then lunch the iteration func). How can I achieve it in React? Is it possible to reach it with lifecycle hooks, like `ComponentWillMount` or `ComponentDidMount`.

My code (it's surely wrong):

```
export default class ExampleClass extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    getData();
  }

  render() {   
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.data.map((v, i) => <li key={i}>{v}</li>)}
      </ul>
    )

  };
}

const getData = () => {
  axios.get(//someURL//)

    .then(function (response) {
      this.setState({data: response.data});
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
};
```

**How to force React to get the JSON before rendering the component?**

Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, use `ComponentWillMount` is one way, just make sure you bind `this` correctly so that `this.setState` refers to the component! You could also just make the get request in the constructor function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show a loading indicator in React Redux app while fetching the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35456935/how-to-show-a-loading-indicator-in-react-redux-app-while-fetching-the-data)

Answer (score 2):

You can do a simple `if` statement in your render function.

```
render () {
  if (Boolean(this.state.data.length)) {
    return <ul>{this.state.data.map((v, i) => <li key={i}>{v}</li>)}</ul>
  }
  return null
}
```

You can also use a higher order component to do the same thing.

```
const renderIfData = WrappedComponent => class RenderIfData extends Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    fetchData()
  }
  render() {
     if (Boolean(this.state.data.length)) {
       return <WrappedComponent {...this.state} />
     }
    return null
  }
}
```

Then you can wrap the presentational layer with the HOC.

```
renderIfData(ExampleClass)
```

Not sure what version of React you are using but you may need to use `<noscript>` instead of `null`.

This is essentially preventing your component from rendering until it has all the data.

Answer (score 2):

Making an AJAX request in `ComponentWillMount` works. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount

You could also just work that logic into your constructor depending on your exact needs.
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#constructor

```
export default class ExampleClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    }
    axios.get(/*someURL*/)
      .then(function (response) {
        this.setState({data: response.data});
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: This is weird, but when Im using componentWillMount, im not able to assign the returned obj to any variable, because no variable exists when it's being done...

Comment: @H.Doe I don't understand what you're saying, please edit your question with an example of what it means for "no variable exists."